# What do you call someone moving arms and legs around much?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a word or short description for someone who...

- ...May well wave their arms and legs around, but not in a clumsy, clowny way, not randomly, not without a purpose.
- ...Is not afraid of getting attention from physical expressions, but may not actively seek it either.
- ...Generally likes to move his\her body around, with no sports activities or physical tasks involved.

Some examples of the movement I'm talking about:

- Dancing, especially without music or being the only one dancing around other people.
- Stretching arms and legs far and wide while not alone.
- Literally jumping around for being in a good mood (I'm talking about grown ups)
- Likes to use the whole body to impersonate something or someone, when explaining or telling a story.

These people are usually extroverts, but 'extrovert' has way too broad meaning.

Comment: There are different words for different situations, with different connotations. Here are three: prance, flail, gesticulate. Which fits your intent?

Comment: Maybe [*effusive*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/effusive), *gesticulative* or *overgesticulative.*

Comment: An *eccentric* personality?

Comment: A *gestural communicator" or, when speaking, a "gestural talker" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[animated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/animated)**

> full of movement and activity

or (although it's not as broadly usable as animated)

**[gesticulator](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gesticulator)**

one who gesticulates, where gesticulate means

> To say or express by gestures.

Answer (score 0):

Physically talkative, demonstrative personality, even perhaps in Don Quixote's sense.